# How can we access data in service passed from activity using bundle ?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, bundle

In Activity:

```
Intent service = new Intent(OverlayShowingService.this, shortLayer.class);
service.putExtra("prevact","overlayService");
startService(service);

stopService(service);
```

What is Bind service? Were can I access my data from activity ? What did I made a miskake?

In service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

public int onStartCommand (Intent Preintent, int flags, int startId) {
    PreActivity = Preintent.getStringExtra("prevact");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: http://www.truiton.com/2014/11/bound-service-example-android/ >> see this link

Comment: What is `shortlayer`? Is `onStartCommand()` in your `Service` ever called? The code you have in `onStartCommand()` looks just fine. You don't need to bind to a `Service` just to pass data to it.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this solution**

For a precise answer to this question on "How to send data via intent from an Activity to Service", Is that you have to override the onStartCommand() method which is where you receive the intent object:

When you create a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) you should override the [onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) method so if you closely look at the signature below, this is where you receive the intent object which is passed to it:

```
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

So, from an activity you will create the intent object to start service and then you place your data inside the intent object for example you want to pass a UserID from Activity to Service:

```
 Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourService.class.getName())
 serviceIntent.putExtra("UserID", "123456");
 context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

When the service is started its [onStartCommand()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) method will be called so in this method you can retrieve the value (UserID) from the intent object for example

```
public int onStartCommand (Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String userID = intent.getStringExtra("UserID");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Hope it would be working fine.

Comment: I already tried this answer on previous posts .. But this didnt help !! It doesnt work in service.